# About the "super init" part of initializing an object in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I was wondering if the "super init" part of initializing an object in Objective C is what creates the isa pointer?

Do you know?

Comment: No it isn't. Any other questions?

Comment: (Oh, and this has nothing to do with Xcode.)

Comment: you could say it is related to xcode, considering that objective-C is pretty much always programmed in xcode.

Comment: @Nejarm_Srit_junsayer, No. Unless you have an issue with Xcode itself, don't blame the IDE. :)

Comment: @Nejarm No. The IDE used is irrelevant. (I've been programming in Objective-C without Xcode for 3 years.) Also, read the tag wiki for the `xcode` tag (it explicitly says "you should not use this tag for general Objective-C programming questions").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation of [`+[NSObject alloc]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000050-alloc):

> Returns a new instance of the receiving class.
>
> The `isa` instance variable of the new instance is initialized to a data
>   structure that describes the class; memory for all other instance
>   variables is set to 0.

So `alloc` is what sets up the `isa` pointer.